# Site is crashed at the time of deploy an app on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I edit anything in my Heroku app (e.g. HTML), as soon as the update is pushed in Git and deployed in Heroku, the application crashes with the [H10 App Crashed](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed) error.

The output of `$ heroku logs --tail`:

> at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=clubfred.herokuapp.com request_id=f1fc405a-cb11-44e8-b5d6-a3d22ca03c59 fwd="124.253.15.8" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https .at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=clubfred.herokuapp.com request_id=05e63f1c-8c32-4ac9-97a2-bb8f936c5bbd fwd="124.253.15.8" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Website is located at https://www.clubfred.nl/ and data comes from **heroku url**.

Comment: Maybe you should share the Heroku logs. Even if you haven't find enything, it might contain information on the error.

Comment: Check the logs, you can access them in your heroku app dashboard. Click on more (top right corner) and view logs. I am sure you missed something in the requirements.txt or procfile.

Comment: @David Guyon  If i didn't change anything in my site. I simply deploy the app in this case it also crashed.I checked my logs but didn't find any reason. See my logs.. at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=clubfred.herokuapp.com request_id=f1fc405a-cb11-44e8-b5d6-a3d22ca03c59 fwd="124.253.15.8" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
.at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=clubfred.herokuapp.com request_id=05e63f1c-8c32-4ac9-97a2-bb8f936c5bbd fwd="124.253.15.8" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https.

Comment: Does your application work locally?

Comment: It works on local.

Comment: Maybe you have a missing Python package. If you compare the output of ``pip list`` locally with the one on your Heroku instance, maybe you'll see a missing package. I am not a Heroku user so I don't know if this remark will be relevant.